# Wordpress plug-in says "There is a new version" but already running the latest

Tags: wordpress

On the plug-ins page in wp-admin, I have a plug-in that says "There is a new version available", specifying that the new version is 1.2. But I'm already running 1.2. It gives me the option to upgrade, so I do that... and it seems successful, though the message remains telling me to upgrade. Is there a process for debugging the issue?

Comment: Are you using a caching plugin of any sort?

Comment: Nope.  It's a new install.  I even tried disabling and resinstalling the plug-in.